# Migrating Fields added to report types using ANT

Tags: deployment, ant, custom-report-type, fls

Question 1:
I have added few fields in custom report types in UAT. Can i move these changes using ANT tool to PRODUCTION?

Usually after deployment, we manually add fields in Report Types in Production which involves lot of effort.

Question 2:

Also, I want to move FLS from UAT to PROD. i Came by few solutions that if i add profiles to my package.xml, FLS too would move to PROD. Will it have any impact on permission sets? Say, i added a new field and made it read only for 'xyz' profile in UAT Env. this field is not added to any permission set. When i migrated this field along with 'xyz' profile using ANT, all the permission in my Higher Environment will stay intact as i am no deploying any changes around that?

Please let me know if i need to be more elaborate or reframe my question?

Comment: You should really do these as two separate questions, better for future google users and better for you now too :)

Comment: @KevinBoyle Its just that second question i didnt feel was all that great:) its just a small confusion i have related to permission set.

Comment: Opening questions is pretty cheap and I personally think that second one has enough merit to standalone and help future searchers. Just my €0.02 though! Does my answer solve your problem? If so, it would be nice if you could mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the [API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_reporttype.htm) that the fields are fully captured in the Metadata XML so will nicely migrate using ANT or anything that builds on the Metadata API. You just need to add `ReportType` to the `package.xml` and list any report types that you want to migrate.

In the screenshot below you can see our Salesforce Release Management solution, [Gearset](https://gearset.com) migrating a changed report type where I have added some fields, removed some others and created a new section. We offer a free no-restriction 30-day trial so you can use Gearset to do your next migration and see if it saves you time.

[image: Gearset migrating a report type]